# navigationItem not showing

Tags: ios, viewdidload, rightbarbuttonitem, navigationitem

I am currently writing an iOS-APP based on mostly UITableViewControllers. The hierarchy is the following:

> AppDelegate -> UINavigationController -> UITableViewController [A]
>   -(didSelectRow: presentModalVC)-> UITabBarController -(contains multiple)-> UINavigationController -> UITableViewController [B]

Now when I try to add a navigationItem in UITableViewController [B] in the viewDidLoad method like so:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(composeTweet:)];
```

the navigationItem does not show.

Comment: Is it possible that someone else is setting rightBarButtonItem after your line of code? Try setting a breakpoint in, say, viewDidAppear and logging the value of the rightBarButtonItem.

Comment: I put a breakpoint into viewDidAppear and I logged the rightBarButtonItem - it is set to the correct value...

Answer (score 0):

Try `self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`

Also, try NSLogging the UINavigationController to see if it's nil or not.

Comment: self.navigationController and self.navigationItem are not nil. The code you suggested doesn't work.